# Как спарсить данные из localStorage с помощью JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript

Как спарсить `"sdasd, dsada, dasdas, dasdas"` в такой вид `["sdasd", "dsada", "dasdas", "dasdas"]`
При JSON.parse выдает ошибку:

> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON
>   data...

Answer (score 3):

У вас строка не в формате JSON, отсюда и ошибка.

Решение такое:

```
var str = "sdasd, dsada, dasdas, dasdas";
var array = str.split(", ");
```